# How to run a shell script from an AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript, command-line, bash, script

I am using a Mac running OSX Yosemite v.10.10.5.

When I try to run my shell script from my AppleScript, I get the following error message:

Error message at AppleScript Script Editor

```
error "sh: /Users/path/to/file/myShellScript.sh: Permission denied" number 126
```

myShellScript.sh

```
cd /Users/myusername/Git/myproject/
git remote remove origin
```

myAppleScript.applescript

```
do shell script "/Users/path/to/file/myShellScript.sh"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To not get that error, you need to make `myShellScript.sh` executable.

In a Terminal, use the following command:

```
chmod u+x /path/to/file/myShellScript.sh
```

Also, you should add a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) to the top of the *script*.

Example: `#!/bin/bash`

Note: Use the appropriate *shebang* for the *shell* you want to process your *script*.

If you do not want to make the *script* executable, although I can't see a reason one wouldn't want to, you can run it in AppleScript as in the following example:

```
do shell script "bash /path/to/file/myShellScript.sh"
```

Note: If you want to use `sh` over `bash`, just substitute it in the command and the *shebang*.

Comment: What about embedding the Shell Script into the Apple Script file? How would you embed few lines of Shell Script into Apple Script?

Answer (score 14):

You can embed your shell script within AppleScript calling `bash` with a `heredoc`.

```
do shell script "/bin/bash -s <<'EOF'
cd /Users/myusername/Git/myproject/
/usr/bin/git remote remove orig
EOF"
```

Answer (score 2):

Play your code with osascript

```
osascript << EOF
tell application "Terminal"
activate
end tell
EOF
```